# AWS API not finding Python modules in pipenv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify to create an API through a lambda function, and following this [tutorial](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/create-a-serverless-python-api-with-aws-amplify-and-flask) to learn it.

Everything seems to work okay when I `amplify push` and test any changes I make, but I would like to use the `amplify mock function <function-name>` to test changes. I'm getting `module not found` for imported modules.

All modules are listed within the pipFile and I'm running my `amplify mock` command within a `pipenv` shell. If I don't use `sudo`, I do get a `failed to get profile credentials` but I'm not sure if that's related.

My pipfile is as follows:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
pipenv = "*"
aws-wsgi = "*"
boto3 = "*"
flask = "*"
flask-cors = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

When I run a `pipenv install <package-names>`, it's adding to the pipfile and installing. Any ideas why the mock testing won't load the modules?